# "Cannot call method 'on' of undefined" issue

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How to solve it?

**View:**

```
App.Views.ModelsIndex = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    initialize: function() {
        this.template = _.template($('#container').html());

        // Cannot call method 'on' of undefined
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template({'model' : this.model}));
        return this;
    }
});
```

**Router:**

```
App.Routers.Models = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index',
        'admin/:id' : 'show'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new App.Collections.Models();
        this.collection.fetch();
    },
    index: function() {
        view = new App.Views.ModelsIndex({'collection' : this.collection});
        $('#container').html(view.render().el);
    },
    show: function(id) {
        alert('entry id:' + id);
    }
});
```

**Collection:**

```
App.Collections.Models = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "/app_dev.php/partner/api/users/1"
    , model: App.Models.Model
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your router passes a collection to your view constructor

```
new App.Views.ModelsIndex({'collection' : this.collection});
```

but you use a model in your view :

```
this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
```

Pick one and stick with it :

```
App.Views.ModelsIndex = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.template = _.template($('#container').html());
        this.collection.on('change', this.render, this);
    }
    ...
});
```